# Does the confidence interval in $N(\theta, 1)$ with lenth $\frac1{n}$ exist?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Suppose that $X_i$ - i.i.d. $N(\theta, 1)$. It's easy to find a confidence interval (with level $\gamma$) for $\theta$ with length $\frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$: $\theta \in (\bar{X} - \epsilon, \overline{X} + \epsilon)$ for $\epsilon = n^{-\frac12}u_{\frac{1+\gamma}2}$ where $u_p$ is a $p$-quantile of $N(0,1)$ and where $\overline{X} = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n}{n}$.

It looks like there's no confidence interval in $N(\theta, 1)$ with lenth $\approx \frac{C}{n}$ but how may we prove it? And how can we find the interval with the smallest lenght (maybe it doesn't have the next form: $(\overline{X} - \epsilon, \overline{X} + \epsilon)$? )

And what about other standard distributions - how may we find the length of the shortest confidence interval, when we know the distribution of $X_i$?

Could you please recommend a book with good introduction to this theme?

Addition: by confidence interval with confidence level $\gamma$ I mean a pair of statistics $T_1^{(n)}(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and $T_2^{(n)}(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ such that $\mathbf{P}_{\theta}( T_1^{(n)}< \theta < T_2^{(n)}) \ge \gamma$ for all $\theta$. By the shortest confidence interval I mean such confidence interval  with confidence level $\gamma$  that $E_{\theta}(T_2^{(n)} - T_1^{(n)})$ takes the least possible value for all $\theta$.

Comment: Please clarify by defining all of your variables.  This may be helpful to you, to spell it out more clearly.

Comment: This question is not very interesting in the case of $N(\theta,1)$ estimation because it is straightforward to see by convexity considerations that a symmetric confidence interval centered around the sample mean will be the shortest one with a given coverage level. It is more interesting in the case of something like Bernoulli(p) data, especially when $\hat{p}$ starts to get close to $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @Ian, could you please tell more details (or reference) about $N(\theta, 1)$? It's not obvious that convexity leads us to a symmetric confidence interval centered around the sample mean.

Comment: @BotnakovN. I would have thought for any continuous symmetric unimodal distribution this was a natural statement

Comment: @Henry, I also think so, but I do not know how to prove it. I would be grateful if you could point to any book where it is well written.

Comment: You can say the density outside the central interval is everywhere lower than inside so to get the same probability you would need to have a wider range.  The sample mean has a $\mathcal N(\mu, \frac1n)$ distribution, so given a fixed $\gamma$ you cannot do better than an interval of width proportional to the standard error of the mean i.e. to $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: @Henry, if we use and interval for $\overline{X}$ then yes, but how can we prove that we should use this statistics?